# How to detect language automatically with Speech Recognition in Python

Tags: python-3.x, api, audio, voice, speech

I am developing an app and I want to detect the language automatically and then print it.

My code:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
audio = r.listen(source)
try:
    # Auto detect the language
    print("You said: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service")
```

Hope you understood.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. There's not a lot of detail here about what specific problem you are having. Try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6):

This may be too late for your answer.  However, someone else may be looking for this in the future.

I have not found a way to auto detect the language using speech_recognition.  The Google API does support multiple languages in the form of an alternate languages array in which it will attempt the different languages you've specified in order to provide a translation.

The way I overcame the issue of detecting a language is that I only have two languages.  I could have more I only have two that I need.  I use a wake word and command.  So I can say (for example) "ok computer translate from Spanish" and the command parser determines that the intent is to translate from Spanish.  I used snips for this but you could just do string tokenization.  In any case, at that point, because I know the intent is "from Spanish" I explicitly set the language code to "es" like this:

```
 said = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es")
```

My SpeechRecord class

```
import speech_recognition as sr

class SpeechRec:
    #https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/voice-assistant/wake-keyword/
    def record(self, lang='en'):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            said = ""

            try:
                #can I detect the language?
                if (lang == 'en') :
                    said = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
                elif (lang == 'es') :
                    said = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es") 

                print(said)
            except Exception as e:
                if (str(e) != ""):
                    print("Exception: " + str(e))

        return said.lower()
```

The listen loop - I call this from a Flask event but it'll work the same in a standalone application

```
WAKE = "computer"
while True:
    text = SpeechRec().record()
    language = "en"

    if text.count(WAKE) > 0:
        text = SpeechRec().record()

        #here I have a call to determine the intent via Snips - I've removed that and just
        #placed a text comparison for simplicity.  Also, to note, using Snips I can reduce
        #the wake word and command to remove two of these 
        #"text = SpeechRec().record()" lines
        if (text == 'translate from spanish'):
            text = SpeechRec().record('es')
        else:
            text = SpeechRec().record()

        #at this point I do the translation and print the value from the translation
```

This is probably not the most elegant solution.  I will probably rewrite this many times in the future.  However, it works well for what I need at the moment.

I hope this helps answer your question.